# Django model derived class

Tags: python, django

i' ve a django model with some fields and methods like this:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    fields = ...

    def methods(self, ...):
        ...
```

. I' d like to create another model with the same fields and methods, however in this new model i' d like to have new fields and methods as well, like this:

```
class Auto(Follow):
    additionalfields = ...

    def additionalmethods(self, ...):
        ...
```

, but in this case the problem is that if i create an **Auto** object, it' ll appear in the **Follow.objects.filter()** QuerySet as well. How could i workaround it? An idea was to specify an **is_auto = models.BooleanField(default = ?)** field in both of the models with relevant value, but that fails during the schemamigration:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'autob' in class 'Auto' clashes
with field of similar name from base class 'Follow'
```

. Any idea how to workaround it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class BaseItem(models.Model):
    #fields and methods

class Follow(BaseItem):
    pass

class Auto(BaseItem):
    #additional fields
```